# libtorrent file_storage invalid : bad allocation

Tags: c++, file-storage, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am following [libtorrent-maketorrent-example](https://libtorrent.org/examples.html#make-torrent)

I am runnin the client with following parameter

```sh
.\client.exe "base_text.txt" -o base_text.torrent -l
```

`file_storage` is declared as below with default constructor

```cpp
    lt::file_storage fs;
```

The program is throwing exception at when it tries to add file

```cpp
lt::add_files(fs, full_path, file_filter, flags);
```

I am guessing the issue could be because file_storage is invalid as the below statment which I added before calling lt::add_files is returns `false` i.e 0

```cpp
std::cout << "Is file storage valid : " << fs.is_valid()<< std::endl;
```

I am getting bad allocation exception for lt::add_files

```
Args[1]= base_text.txt
Is file storage valid : 0
ERROR: bad allocation
```

and full path is **C:\workspace\Project1%20POC\client\base_text.torrent**

How do I solve this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was file path contained `%` project folder name was **Project1%20POC** 
I renamed it to **Project1-POC** and also made sure that full path is less than 260 characters which is the default threshold in Windows.

Now `lt::add_files` not throwing bad allocation exception and the next line `lt::create_torrent` creates the torrent.